# How do I get shadow to show up in react native iOS?

Tags: react-native

My shadow is not working on iOS.
What am I doing wrong?

```css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor:'#F8F8F8',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    height:60,
    paddingTop: 20,
    borderBottomWidth:0,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 5
    },
    shadowRadius: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    elevation:3,
    position:'relative',
  },
});
```

Comment: Shadow is iOS only. On Android use `elevation`

Comment: I use elevation too. Any suggestion on my code??

Comment: Please format your question code

Answer (score 7):

You can use this to generate shadows for both iOS and Android
[React native shadow generator](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/)

Comment: Great! but it seems that this doesn't affect ios...

Comment: For me, it worked like a charm for iOS as well.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I tried it and it works fine on my already created TouchableOpacity Text:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.TestView} onPress={()=> { this.doAction; }}
    >
    <Text style={[styles.normalText, styles.headerText, { color: colors.lighterPrimaryColor }]}>
        TEST
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And in style:

```
 privateMessagesView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
    shadowRadius: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    elevation: 3,
    position: 'relative',
  },
```

And here's the results on my android device:
[image]

If you want better results you can use [react-native-cardview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cardview) or you can use a card from a UI components library like `native-base`, `react-native-material-design` ..etc If you're using one.

Answer (score 2):

**Shadow in react native**

```
import {Platform} from "react-native";
```

add below styles to View

```
{
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
    ...Platform.select({
      android: {
        elevation: 2,
      },
      ios: {
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 1,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        shadowRadius: 1.41,
      },
    }),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (working for me):

```
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: "#fff",
flexDirection: "row",
marginTop: 15,
height: 35,
width: 170,
marginHorizontal: 20,
marginBottom : 10,
shadowColor: '#000000',
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
shadowOpacity: 0.5,
shadowRadius: 5, 
elevation: 1.5,
borderColor: '#e6e6e6'
```